# Java JInternalFrame remains fixed in dimension and position

Tags: java, frame, jinternalframe

I wonder whether I can do the following with Java:I would like to have a parent window, inside this window, I create a child windown. That child window has a predefined size and position (screen position) so that no matter how I move / resize the parent window, the child one remains unchanged. Of course the relation child / parent is still respected: only the common/overlapped region of the child and parent window will be visible in the parent window.

I already tried with JInternalFrame to create the child window. I can fix the dimension of JInternalFrame but not its position. Whenever I move the parent window, the JInternalFrame moves together.

Can you give me some helps to realize such feature?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can alwas use [ComponentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html). It has `componendMoved` and `componentResized` callbacks.

Also `SwingUtilities` will be helpfull with calculating required position or 'internal' window with this method: [convertPointFromScreen(java.awt.Point,java.awt.Component)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#convertPointFromScreen(java.awt.Point,%20java.awt.Component))  Good luck!

Comment: Thank Antoniossss for the answer. I will give it a try. From the Java doc ("Component events are provided for notification purposes ONLY; The AWT will automatically handle component moves and resizes internally")  I thought that the ComponentListener is just a post-event, and I would search for pre-event or at least ontime-event :-). Indeed from the post-event I can reverse things done by AWT.